# How would I send values in a vector to a class?

Tags: c++

I'm assigned to translate an excel spreadsheet into a C++ program.

The excel spreadsheet is a monthly budget report in which the user has to set the cost/income of each of the services he uses, let's say, water, gas, electricity, amazon.com, etc.

After that, the user is asked again to submit the percentage he pays to calculate what he pays individually for each service... I'm somewhat lost in that sentence.

In order to do this, I ask the user to enter the values using a do-while:

```
double value;
cin >> value;
do {
  passToVector(value);
  cin >> value;
} while(value != 0);
```

The passToVector function then stores the values on an expensesList vector:

```
void passToVector(double value){
  vector<double> expensesList;
  expensesList.push_back(value);
};
```

this is where I'm getting lost, the class should be able to receive those values in order to update them when needed. Here it is an example of what my class looks like:

```
class Expenses {
  private:
    double percentage = 0.00;
    double mortgage = 0.00;
    double electric = 0.00;
    double gas = 0.00;
    double water = 0.00;
  public:
    // Set percentage each person brings
    void setPercentage(double per) { percentage = per; }
    double getPercentage() const { return percentage / 100; }
    // Calculate Total Expenses by Person
    void calculatePersonExpenses() {
      double result = mortgage * getPercentage();
      double result2 = electric * getPercentage();
      double result3 = gas * getPercentage();
      double result4 = water * getPercentage();

      cout << "Mortgage:                      $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << result << endl;
      cout << "Electricity:                   $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << result2 << endl;
      cout << "Gas(Home):                     $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << result3 << endl;
      cout << "Water:                         $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << result4 << endl;
    }
};
```

First, I'm assuming I need to create setters and getters for each of the services but if I do that...why would I need a vector function?; right now the only functions that I have are the ones for setPercentage. The task is just to store the values in a Vector of Class Objects data structure.

How can I update those values automatically when I need to?; Do I have to send the values to the class or is my approach totally wrong?

Hopefully I could explain myself.

Comment: Are you really using _all_ the C++ standards simultaneously?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Have you talked to your teacher about your misunderstandings? You likely need to talk through this with someone. It's not a good entry for a Q&A database. Good luck!

Comment: You maybe need to clarify the question a bit more. A "Vector of Class Objects" probably means a vector of `Expenses` and not a vector of doubles? Like one entry (of type `Expenses`) for each month? Also please note that `passToVector` does exactly nothing. the vector is destroyed as soon as the function ends.

Comment: Well, that's where I'm getting lost. I'm not sure what type of Vector to use, it was not specified. The reports are not by month, they are just by service. You type the cost of the services you use, then type the percentage that you pay and after tha, the program is supposed to show you the amount you pay individually for each service....does that make sense at all?

Comment: @Kirasiris giva an example input, and the output you want. Maybe then we can understand you better.

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```
void passToVector(double value){
  vector<double> expensesList;
  expensesList.push_back(value);
};
```

you must realize that `expensesList` is a local variable. It is created inside of the scope of this function, **and deleted at the end**. I.e. You lose all your actions.

Now, you can either have a vector of expenses:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T ReadCin(std::string_view const& str = "") {
    if (!str.empty()) std::cout << str;
    T retVal;
    std::cin >> retVal;
    return retVal;
}

class Expenses {
private:
    double percentage{ 0 };
    double mortgage{ 0 };
    double electric{ 0 };
    double gas{ 0 };
    double water{ 0 };
public:
    Expenses() = default;
    Expenses(double percentage, double mortgage, double electric, double gas, double water)
        :percentage(percentage), mortgage(mortgage), electric(electric), gas(gas), water(water)
    {}

    static Expenses NewItem() { return {
        ReadCin<decltype(percentage)>("What percentage?\n"),
        ReadCin<decltype(mortgage)>("What mortgage?\n"),
        ReadCin<decltype(electric)>("What electric?\n"),
        ReadCin<decltype(gas)>("What gas?\n"),
        ReadCin<decltype(water)>("What water?\n") };
    }
};

#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<Expenses> expensesList;
    expensesList.push_back(Expenses::NewItem());
}
```

Or you can have a list of expenses in the class `Expenses`

```
class Expenses {
private:
    std::vector<double> expensesList {};
    //[...etc]
public:
    void AddExpense(double value) noexcept {
        expenseList.push_back(value);
    }
```

It all depends on what you want.